# Crittercism Cordova / Phonegap plugin spewing error: [Crittercism] warning: responseCode == 0 should be inside 100-599 for error == nil

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, crittercism

I'm building a Cordova app and using the Crittercism plugin for error logging. I am getting a constant stream of errors when I run it from Xcode:

[Crittercism] warning: responseCode == 0 should be inside 100-599 for error == nil

I can't find anything about this in the documentation, stack overflow, the Apteligent website, et cetera. Does anyone have any idea if this is a problem?

Cordova 6.4.0
Cordova iOS 4.3.1
cordova-plugin-apteligent: 3.1.0

Thanks!

Comment: So reading the code it probably means nil was passed to crittercismLogNetworkRequest which seems weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim, we have released a new version for PhongeGap 3.3.1 as given in the below link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-apteligent

This should fix your issue. Please make sure to follow the steps given in the following doc :https://docs.apteligent.com/development_platforms/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

Tim, we are currently facing some issue on PhoneGap integration and this is being looked upon by the Engineering team. We will update here as soon as we receive more information on it.

Comment: Thanks. Would this issue also be likely to cause a crash deleteStackFillerInformation when it is called with NSNull from crittercismLogUnhandledException?

Comment: Did you fix it? I'd like to publish the latest version of our app.... Currently we have removed crittercism/apteligent from the build

Comment: Did you fix it?